# Can std::io::BufReader on a TcpStream lead to data loss?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, rust, rust-tokio

Can a single instance of [`std::io::BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) on a [`tokio::net::TcpStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.12/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html) lead to data loss when the `BufReader` is used to [`read_until`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.12/tokio/io/fn.read_until.html) a given (byte) delimiter?

That is, is there any possibility that after I use the `BufReader` for:

```
let buffer = Vec::new();
let reader = BufReader::new(tcp_stream);
tokio::io::read_until(reader, delimiter, buffer)
   .map(move |(s, _)| s.into_inner())
```

a following `tokio::io::read` using the same stream would return data that is actually beyond the delimiter + 1, causing therefore data loss?

---

I have an issue (and [complete reproducible example on Linux](https://gist.github.com/gliderkite/9a084ed3405f08e473c346a0d0ff0ada)) that I have trouble explaining if the above assumption isn't correct.

I have a TCP server that is supposed to send the content of a file to multiple TCP clients following multiple concurrent requests.

Sometimes, using always the same inputs, the data received by the client is less than expected, therefore the transfer fails.

The error is not raised 100% of the times (that is, some of the client requests still succeed), but with the 100 tries defined in `tcp_client.rs` it was always reproducible for at least one of them.

The sequence of data transferred between client and server is composed by:

1. the client send a request
2. the server read the request and send a response
3. the client read the response
4. the server send the file data
5. the client read the file data

This issue is only reproducible only if steps 1, 2 and 3 are involved, otherwise it works as expected.

The error is raised when this [`tokio::io::read`](https://gist.github.com/gliderkite/9a084ed3405f08e473c346a0d0ff0ada#file-tcp_client-rs-L30) (used to read the file content) returns 0, as if the server closed the connection, even is the server is actually up and running, and all the data has been sent (there is an assertion after [`tokio::io::copy`](https://gist.github.com/gliderkite/9a084ed3405f08e473c346a0d0ff0ada#file-tcp_server-rs-L32) and I checked the TCP packets using a packet sniffer). On a side note, in all my runs the amount of data read before the error was always > 95% than the one expected.

Most importantly the `common.rs` module defines 2 different `read_*` functions:

- [`read_until`](https://gist.github.com/gliderkite/9a084ed3405f08e473c346a0d0ff0ada#file-common-rs-L22) currently used.
- [`read_exact`](https://gist.github.com/gliderkite/9a084ed3405f08e473c346a0d0ff0ada#file-common-rs-L33) not used.

The logic of the 2 is the same, they need to read the request/response (and both client and server can be updated to use one or the other). What is surprising is that the bug presents itself only when `tokio::io::read_until` is used, while `tokio::io::read_exact` works as expected.

Unless, I misused `tokio::io::read_until` or there is a bug in my implementation, I expected both versions to work without any issue. What I am seeing instead is [this panic](https://gist.github.com/gliderkite/9a084ed3405f08e473c346a0d0ff0ada#file-tcp_client-rs-L46) being raised because some clients cannot read all the data sent by the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is described in the [documentation for `BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) (emphasis mine):

> When the `BufReader` is dropped, **the contents of its buffer will be discarded**.

The next sentence is *correct* but not extensive enough:

> Creating multiple instances of a `BufReader` on the same stream can cause data loss.

The `BufReader` has read data from the underlying source and put it in the buffer, then you've thrown away the buffer. The data is gone.